# Help with a trigonometric limit

Tags: calculus, limits

> Find the limit and determine if the function is continuous at the point that is being approached:
>   $$\lim_{y \to 1}\;\; \mathrm{sec}\;(y\;\mathrm{sec}^2y \;-\;\mathrm{tan}^2y\;-\;1)$$

My try: I just rewrote it so that it reads

$$\lim_{y \to 1}\;(\frac{1}{\mathrm{cos}})  (\frac{y}{\mathrm{cos}^2y} \; - \; \frac{\mathrm{sin}^2y}{\mathrm{cos}^2y} \; - \; 1).$$

I'm not sure if this is correct, and I don't know how to proceed.
Answers: the limit is $1$, and yes, the function is continuous. I would like to see the worked out steps to understand how they arrived at that answer.
Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you reported the correct text? Writing $\frac{1}{cos}$ means nothing, in any case.

Comment: @egreg yes, that's how the question was written. why does $\frac{1}{cos}$ mean nothing? isn't it the reciprocal of secant?

Comment: You probably mean $\frac{1}{\cos{(\dotsc)}}$ rather than $(\frac{1}{cos})(\dotsc)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let us consider a little notation:

It is true that $\sec(x) = \frac{1}{\cos (x)}$, and so with this limit we do not say 
$$ \lim_{y \to 1}\;(\frac{1}{\mathrm{cos}})  (\frac{y}{\mathrm{cos}^2y} \; - \; \frac{\mathrm{sin}^2y}{\mathrm{cos}^2y} \; - \; 1)$$ becuase $\frac{1}{\cos}$ is meaningless. The cosine is a function and that function has to be over a variable, in this case $x$, so $\cos(x) = f (x)$ and writing $\cos$ is like writing $f$: there is no variable, and the statement is meaningless.

Now your limit: $$ \lim_{y \to 1} \sec (y\ \sec^2(y) - \tan^2(y) -1)$$
Which we simplify to 
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{y \to 1} \sec (y\ \sec^2(y) - \tan^2(y) -1) & = \lim_{y \to 1} \sec (y\ \sec^2(y) - (\tan^2(y)+1))\\
& = \lim_{y \to 1} \sec (y\ \sec^2(y) - sec^2(y)) \\
& = \lim_{y \to 1} \sec ((y\ -1) \sec^2(y)) \ \ \ \ .
\end{align}$$
Now we take the limit by plugging in 1
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{y \to 1} \sec ((y\ -1) sec^2(y)) & = \sec( (1 - 1) \sec^2(1))\\
& = \sec(0)\\
& = 1
\end{align}$$
as desired.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$y \sec^2(y) - \tan^2(y)-1 = y \sec^2(y) - \sec^2(y) = (y-1)\sec^2(y)$$
Hence,
$$\lim_{y \to 1}\sec((y-1)\sec^2(y)) = \sec(0) = 1$$

Comment: You also can use Taylor expansions starting with the expansions around y=1 of Sec[y] and Tan[y]. You only need firt order terms. From these expansions, compute y Sec[x]^2 - Tan[x]^2 - 1 just keeping the first order terms. Finally, apply the first order Taylor expansion for Sec of your previous result. I confess that this is much less elegant to the other solutions given here